# Detect if a form has been sent

Tags: php, zend-framework, submit

In my controller, i need some instructions to be launched only if a form has been sent.

This is my controller:

```
public function indexAction() 
  {    

       $form   = array();
       $submit = $this->getRequest()->getParam('submit');


        if (!empty($submit))         
        {         

            $lastname = $this->getRequest()->getParam('last-name');
            $name     = $this->getRequest()->getParam('name');
            $email    = $this->getRequest()->getParam('email');

            $form     = array(

                'lastname' => $lastname,
                'name'     => $name,
                'email'    => $email);          

            $confirm      = Tools::checkInscription($form);

            var_dump($confirm);
            exit();

           if ($confirm === true)
           {        
                  Tools::saveUser($form);   
           }
           else 
           {
                  // Mets une variable a true pour savoir dans ta vu que tu as une erreur.  
                  $this->_redirect('/inscription');
           }


        }



  }
```

the problem is $submit always seems returning null.

My view:

```
        <form id="formulaire">
            <div class="msg">
                <p class="error">Merci de vérifier les champs en rouge</p>
            </div>
            <div class="last-name">
                <input type="text" class="error" id="last-name" name="last-name" placeholder="Votre nom" />
            </div>
            <div class="name">
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Votre prénom"/>
            </div>
            <div class="email">
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Votre email"/>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" title="Valider"></button>
        </form>
```

Can anyone help to find what i'm doing wrong
thanks in advance

Comment: shouldn't `<button type="submit"` be `<input type="submit"` ?

Comment: u r form doesnt have action ??

Comment: Your button needs a `name="submit"`, doesn't it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your submit button should be an input :

```
<input type="submit" title="Valider" />
```

And your form should have an action :

```
<form id="formulaire" method="POST" action="some_page.php">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set your form method to POST you can check it with this:

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<input type="submit" title="Valider">
```

instead of

```
<button type="submit" title="Valider"></button>
```

And change

```
<form id="formulaire" action="" method="post">
```

instead of

```
<form id="formulaire">
```